# How to read limited number of input separated by space in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

While coding for competitions in codechef, I face this problem with python, to read

> ```
> 3     # number of required input  
> 1 4 2 # inputs
> ```

to read input i used:

```
data=list(map(int,input().split()))
```

but it will read any number of inputs and will store as list.
How to restrict size of input or size of list? while writing input it should accept only input with spaces

Comment: Are you having any problems with the above? Generally the purpose of the above is for languages that need to pre-allocate memory - not an issue for Python. Checking that there is only `n` inputs seems overkill given the contract already states it will only pass in `n` inputs. If you really need to fail on more inputs just `assert len(data) == 3`

Comment: actually, problem is while competition, if we specify n as number of input, it should not accept more than n inputs, or after passing n inputs it should come out of loop.

Comment: Does it really state "it should not accept more than n inputs"? If the contract is that it will only pass n inputs then you don't need to test for it... I've only seen the latter not the former. You can always slice `data[:3]` to only take the first `3` but I still think this is overkill.

Comment: i wanted to take it like for(i=0;i<n;i++) {sacnf(%d);}

Comment: yes,i agree that, this is overkill, but this is the need in competition, slicing will be done after accepting inputs, but i wanted to take only n inputs and move to next executable statement.

Comment: `stdin` is buffered so you can't just accept `n` inputs you will get the whole line of all the inputs. If that is greater than `n` you get to decide how to deal with them.

Comment: that's the actual issue. well thanks for discussion, if you find any solution to this issue in future, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To separate input by spaces:

```
data=list(map(int,input().split(' ')))
```

To verify wether the correct amount of numbers were passed:

```
if len(data) > n: # where n is your number of required input
    # Raise an exception or ask for the input again.
```

Comment: i wanted to accept only n number of data and then come out of the loop, like we do in java, using for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You may use list comprehension syntax:

```
req_size = int(input().strip())
data = [int(i) for i in input().strip().split()[:req_size]]
```

explanation: `.strip()` method removes `\n` and oyher whitespace symbols from the start and end of the string. `.split()` method splits string by any whitespace symbol. If you prefer to split only by whitespaces, use ' ' character explicitly: `.split(' ')`. Split method returns list, and you can use [:req_size] to get firsr `req_size` elements from it (stabdart list syntax). Then `int` type applied to your data with list comprehension syntax (shorthand for the `for` loop).